# Setting an old vector equal to a new vector

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, stl, stdvector

Say I'm making a class:

```
#import <vector>

class Example {
    std::vector<float> v;

    public:
        Example(std::vector<float>);
};
```

How do I set the existing vector *v* equal to the vector passed through the constructor? Is there some "accepted" way of doing that?

I've thought about looping through, and just adding them.. but it seems "forced".

```
#import "Example.h"

Example::Example(std::vector<float> u) {
    //or however a vector iterates! :-)
    for (int i = 0; i < u.size; ++i)
        this->v.push_back(u.at(i));
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++11 provides the *best* way to do this if you want to use the `std::vector` you're passing into `Example`, as in you don't want to allocate and copy to a new `std::vector`. This is called a [move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor):

```
class Example {
    std::vector<float> _v;
public:
    Example(std::vector<float>&& v) : _v(std::move(v)) {}
};
```

In your code you can force this to be called like this:

```
std::vector<float> foo{4.0, 8.0, 15.0, 16.0, 23.0, 42.0};
Example bar = std::move(foo);
```

A [copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) is used when you want to make a copy of the argument:

```
class Example {
    std::vector<float> _v;
public:
    Example(const std::vector<float>& v) : _v(v) {}
};
```

And can be used like:

```
std::vector<float> foo{4.0, 8.0, 15.0, 16.0, 23.0, 42.0};
Example bar = foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the copy constructor:

```
Example::Example(const std::vector<float>& u) 
: v(u)
{ }
```

Note that I'm taking by `u` by reference to const, not by value.

If you were to insist on not just copying the `vector`, which is definitely the most efficient way, then `vector` also has an [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) method which takes a range (the 4th overload):

```
Example::Example(const std::vector<float>& u) 
{
    v.insert(v.end(), u.begin(), u.end());
}
```

Comment: Would I not need to write it like "Example::Example(..." ?

Comment: @jaska : Yes, he's just mimicing the typo in your question. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn Haha yep! Fixed both :)

Comment: Is there a problem if I don't pass a "const std::vector<float> &" to the constructor (with 'const' and '&')?  Wouldn't I need to make whatever is being passed to it from other source files the same? They won't be constant... (BTW - I'm more of a plain C guy - C++ can be like Greek sometimes ;D )

Comment: @jaska If you just take `u` by value, you'll make 2 copies: one into the constructor (into `u`) and then one more into your variable (`v`). If you take by const-reference, you just have the one copy - since `u` *is* the argument you're passing in, rather than a copy of it.

Comment: *"insist on not just copying the vector, which is definitely the most efficient way, then"* - firstly, why would you even speculate on such a strange insistence when there's no indication of any such reluctance in the question; secondly, "just copying" is not always the most efficient way - also providing a move constructor would be good.  @jaska: `const&` is telling the compiler that the `Example` constructor won't need to modify it - you can still call that constructor with a variable that's non-`const` in the caller's context.